# How does YARP load balancing work with Azure App Service Automatic scaling?

Tags: autoscaling, azure-appservice, ms-yarp

I have a angular frontend and three microservices developed using .NET 7 as mentioned below :

1. APIGatway using YARP 2.0 (Latest version)
2. Microservice1
3. Microservice2

I have the following deployment options:

1. Angular Frontend hosted in Azure App Service
2. All the Microservices are also hosted in individual Azure App Serives

I deployed the above setup and validated and found working fine. At present I have only one destination configured  in each backend microservice to forward the requests coming from the angular frontend-> ApiGateway application. But in case of PRODUCTION deployment which has Automatic scaling enabled then in that case how to configure the load balancing policy

Reference : https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/load-balancing.html

Can anyone please help me here by providing their guidance

Comment: in case of automatic scaling of API , you do not have to configure additional endpoint in YARP cluster because there will be no additional endpoints